# php array_push with index and key

Tags: php, array-push

I am not sure if I got the terms right in my title, but I am trying to do a php `array_push` like so

```
array_push($countryList, "US" => "United States");
```

but this gives me a syntax error.

Am I not doing this properly?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it is posted...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding like

```
$countryList["US"] = "United States";
```

Pushing a value into an array automatically creates a numeric key for it.

When adding a key-value pair to an array, you already have the key, you don't need one to be created for you. Pushing a key into an array doesn't make sense. You can only set the value of the specific key in the array.

```
// no key
array_push($array, $value);
// same as:
$array[] = $value;

// key already known
$array[$key] = $value
```

;

Answer (score 1):

Try using this array merge method :

```
$countryList = array_merge($countryList, array("US" => "United States"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a value with key in an array then you may use the following function:

```
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}

Usage: $array= array_push_assoc($array, 'US', 'United States');
```

Answer (score -2):

Refer to online php doc ...

"US" => "United States"   is not a var !